# Django типы пользователей

Tags: django

Делаю опросник. Нужно сделать 2 вида пользователей:

1) Обычный пользователь (будет опросы проходить)

2) Модератор (будет их создавать)

Собственно вопрос: Можно ли добавить в стандартного юзера дополнительные группы, или лучше сделать новую модель для деления пользователей и наследовать от User?

Comment: Наследовать `User` как раз не надо. Либо наследуй `AbstractBaseUser`, если у тебя полностью кастомная модель пользователя, со своими полями. Либо наследуй `AbstractUser`, если стандартная модель `User` тебе подходит и ты просто хочешь добавить дополнительных полей информации.

Comment: То, что ты описываешь, решается на уровне groups/permissions, причем тебе хватит ванильного джанго. У тебя должна быть модель опроса, скажем, класс `Poll`, создаешь к нему content type, к нему создаешь новую permission, допустим, с именем `can_create`. Создаешь новую группу `mods`, добавляешь в нее созданную permission и юзеров. Затем во view проверяй на наличие `can_create`: `if request.user.has_perm('myapp.can_create'): ...` И никаких доп. классов для пользователей не надо.